# force workflow to shutdown

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

We are running informatica 10.1 after patch and restart of servers there a workflow we cannot stop or abort.

```
(is_02_unicode 15-05-2017 12:53:03) Abort Workflow: ERROR: Cannot stop or abort workflow [id = 47547] or a task within the workflow. The specified run id     [5205034] is not found on this Integration Service.
```

It seems like the repository thinks it have a running task workflow id 5205034 but the DIS does not.

The configuration is a 4 node windows installation with af DIS Grid. 
We dont want to restart DIS if it can be avoid.

I I have seen post refering to killing the process from the admin console, but i can't find out how

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hope this helps : https://network.informatica.com/thread/59084

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll need to restart the Integration Service. Try to `UnSchedule` the workflow first.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the process id and kill the process in terminal

Comment: It has no process id, but the repository things it has so i cannot kill it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If Informatica is installed in UNIX server, go to the UNIX terminal and run 
ps -aef |grep workflowname. You will get the processID. run kill -9 processID. It will kill the process from Backend.

If Informatica is on windows server, then try to restart the server.